# Async operations in modal callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, semantic-ui

I'm using the semantic-ui modal to allow users to insert data. It has an onApprove callback which allows you to return false to keep the modal open if there are any problems. My data is inserted into a DB, which returns false if there's any error. What's the best way of keeping the modal open if there's an error during this async operation?

Here's my code (coffeescript):

```
$('#verification-modal')
.modal('setting', {
    detachable: false,
    onApprove: validateVerificationForm
    closable: false
})

 validateVerificationForm = () ->
      formData = $('.form').serializeArray()
      formatted = format($formData);

      ID_Details.insert(formatted, (errs, id) ->
         if errs
             false
         else
            true
```

Obviously the anonymous function is returning true/false into the context of the function. What's the best way to return it to the modal?

Comment: You can return false, on success in all conditions then close it using `$('.modal').modal('hide')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local reactive variable:

```
var data = new ReactiveDict();

Template.modalTemplate.created = function() {
  data.set('isError', false);
};

Template.modalTemplate.helpers({
  isError: function() {
    return data.get('isError');
  },
});

var yourMethodWithAsync = function() {
  ...
  async(..., function(error) {
    if(error) {
      data.set('isError', true);
    }
    ...
  });
};
```

Comment: This is a cool idea, but doesn't work

  isError: function() {
       yourMethodWithAsync()
       return data.get('isError');
  }

 `return data.get('isError')` evaluates immediately and thus will return the result of the last evaluation, not the current one.